# API Call Optimization within R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, performance, api, optimization

I'm struggling with APIs.  I'm hopeful that somebody can help me with my specific example.  I'm running Rstudio on an AWS instance.

I'm running the following code to pull data from an API call.  I'm getting roughly 90 - 125 calls per minute.  However, I'm allowed to pull up to 600 / minute.  I could use help optimizing this.  I'm not able to figure it out.  I'm hopeful this is a simple question for somebody.  Please provide code that would work.  Thanks.

```
out_table <- data.frame()

for (var in pull_list) {
  
  data_out     <- paste(web_address, var,"&apikey=", api_variable, sep="")
  data_out_df  <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(file=data_out))
  
  out_table <- rbind(out_table, data_out_df)
}
```

Comment: Run multiple R processes in parallel, call the API from each one

Comment: What AWS service are you trying to invoke here.?

Comment: Do you have an example of how the multiple R processes in parallel would work?  I'm unable to figure this one out.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.